# Access a child field in a parent-child soql query

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, force.com

I want to return all the opportunity contact roles for each opportunity where it's roles for an Opportunity, and I want to access a field in the contact role. my query looks ok, but I can't access the fields directly in Apex. Also, how do I access this in Visualforce?

Help?

```
        Opportunity opp = [SELECT id, Name, StageName,
    (select contact.name, contact.phone from OpportunityContactRoles where isPrimary = true  )  
    FROM Opportunity
    where id = '006e0000003V3NNAA0'];

    system.debug(opp.OpportunityContactRoles.contact.id);
```

Error:

`Invalid foreign key relationship: Opportunity.OpportunityContactRoles`

Visualforce:

`<apex:outputText value="{!opps.???????`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is in how you're accessing the Opportunity Contact Roles. Your query is returning this data as a list; you need to select a specific Opportunity Contact Role.

Try this:

```
System.Debug(opp.OpportunityContactRoles[0].Contact.Name);
```